# CSS rule to target text between 2 tags

Tags: css

HTML:

```
<p>
    <span>blah</span>
    blah
    <span>blah</span>
    lorum ipsum
    <br>
    <span>blah</span>
    blah
    <span>blah</span>
    lorum ipsum
</p>
```

Given this HTML, is there any way that I can style all of the `blah` one color (inside *and outside* the spans) and style the remaining text a different color?  It must be a pure CSS solution with support for IE7 and above.

Obviously I can do something like this:

```
p {
    color:#000;
}
p span {
    color:#f00;
}
```

but this leaves one `blah` black.

Comment: Check out this like post
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196630/hide-text-node-in-element-but-not-children][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196630/hide-text-node-in-element-but-not-children

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way that I can style all of the `blah` one color, and style the remaining text a different color?

There's no way of doing this with pure CSS.

You'll either need to change your markup (add another semantic span), or use some JavaScript to modify the markup at runtime.

As a long shot, if your `span` text is all on the first line, you could style `:first-line`.

Comment: This kind of thing is what they made tags for :) Seriously though, he'll need some javascript or something.

Comment: Ha, no hope of it being on one line.  The real markup is nasty, with several of these 2 span arrangements contained in a single paragraph.  I have no control over anything other than plain CSS that gets injected.

Comment: @shanethehat: There's (still) simply no way to do this. Sorry.

Comment: I thought as much, time to break the bad news to my designer!

Comment: @shanethehat, i feel your pain; especially if you're working with a picky designer.