# CSS selector for content of an element tag

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This sound silly, but I want to apply a CSS to a content inside and element tag.

Example:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <a href="#">Tag 1</a>
    ,
    <a href="#">Tag 2</a>
    ,
    <a href="#">Tag 3</a>
</div>
```

Is there any possibility that I'll be able to remove or hide the comma `,` every between the  tag using CSS? I have no idea how to tweak a generated output for tags that contains comma.. so I was thinking if this would be possible using CSS?

Comment: Can you alter your HTML at all? I'm thinking of adding a span around the comma.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide text node in element, but not children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196630/hide-text-node-in-element-but-not-children)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work, allthough css might not be the best way. How did they get there in the first place... Css is for style (hence StyleSheet), not for content.

```
.wrap{
    visibility:collapse;
}

.wrap a{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

[And a jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u9PNJ/)
CSS3 selectors are fun, but can be difficult to understand what is happening, and the support for older browsers is minimal.

[Hide text node in element, but not children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196630/hide-text-node-in-element-but-not-children)

Comment: Why the downvote? Please dont downvote and say nothing, I might improve the answer a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this css for hiding your comma.

```
.wrap{
    visibility:collapse;
}
.wrap a{
    visibility:visible
}
```