# How to hide text only in a div with multiple elements JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html

In the following div:-

```
<div>
     My Text that needs to be hidden 
    <span style="font-size: 21px">Other text Other things</span>
</div>
```

I just want to hide the text `My Text that needs to be hidden`. Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide text node in element, but not children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196630/hide-text-node-in-element-but-not-children)

Comment: Basically the question doesn't have an obvious search text for it. May be that's how I missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide("slow",function(){
      alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Hide</button>
<div>
     <p>My Text that needs to be hidden </p>
    <span style="font-size: 21px">Other text Other things</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Html:

```
<div>
    <span id="mySpan" >My Text that needs to be hidden</span> // Add a span with a id
    <span style="font-size: 21px">Other text Other things</span>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mySpan').css('display', 'none');
});
```