# Hide or remove part of the content of an HTML element using CSS

Tags: html, css, hide

**The problem**

I cannot alter the way in whcih the HTML below is output, but I do need to amend the way in which it is displayed.  I know I can achieve my desired results with `jQuery`, but I'd like to do it with pure `CSS` possible?

**What exactly I need to do**

I need to show the `input` from the HTML below, but the `label` itself is superfluous.  The tag can stay or go, I'm not bothered by that, but `Username` and `<br>` need to be gone.

Obviousely I cannot use `label[for="user_login"]{ display: none; }`, as this will fail because it will hide everything within the selector.

**The original HTML**

```
<label for="user_login">
    Username
    <br>
    <input id="user_login" class="input" type="text" size="20" value="" name="log">
</label>
```

**The desired HTML**

```
<label for="user_login">
    <input id="user_login" class="input" type="text" size="20" value="" name="log">
</label>
```

**jQuery approach**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var username_label = $('label[for="user_login"]'),
        username_input = username_label.find('input');

    username_label.html(username_input);

});
```

**Why I don't want to use jQuery**

The login for in question is displayed differently depending on screen size.  On smaller devices I requre the labels hidden (to save space), while on larger screens the label should still be visible.  Using the jQuery approach will remove the labels in both cases.

While I know I can check the screen widht on load, and then use `resize` event (if necessary), should the screen size change (on a tablet, portrait to landscape for example) the labels could be removed and then not visible when they need to be.

**Question**

Can I achieve this result (or similar) with pure `CSS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this css:

```
label {
    visibility:collapse;
}

label input {
    visibility: visible; 
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/entgqjzk/

I modified the css I found at [Hide text node in element, but not children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196630/hide-text-node-in-element-but-not-children)

**edit:**

This doesn't remove the whitespace as you indicated.
I can't come up with anything better than a combination of jQuery and css, it's not the most beautiful code ever but it does work for this situation in which you don't have control over the html:

http://jsfiddle.net/entgqjzk/2/

The css class "hidden-for-mobile" could be used for example combined with a seperate stylesheet for mobile devices (or pseudo selectors for different screen sizes)

Comment: Very close... While this hides `Username` and `<br>` the space that they occupy is still taken above the `inptu`. If you know of a way to remove that I'd be greatful. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. In conjunction with your original suggestion, I'm currently working on setting `label` to `position: relative;`, and `input` to `position: absolute;` and `top: 0;`.  It's not quite working yet, but nearly there...

Comment: Got it! I posted the full CSS below, but it was your initial suggestion that made it possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pseudo classes? http://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/

Comment: I have, and while the link you supply is great, much of the content is based around `whouldn't it be good if this existed` as opposed currently available pseudo classes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @geoffreydv for the idea of using `visibility`.

In conjunction with that, I was able to use the CSS below to effectively hide the whitespace occuped by the text within the label.

```
body.login #loginform label[for="user_login"],
body.login #loginform label[for="user_pass"]{
    display:        inline-block;
    height:         50px;
    position:       relative;
    visibility:     collapse;
    width:          300px;
}

body.login #loginform input#user_login,
body.login #loginform input#user_pass{
    margin:         0;
    position:       absolute;
    top:            0;
    visibility:     visible;
    width:          300px;
}
```