# Remove Text In <div>

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using JQUERY and CSS to edit a websites default content, however I have come across the following code:

```
<div id="SortOptions">
    Sort by: 
    <select id="SortMain" class="improvedcatalogdropdown">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Relevance</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I need to **remove the text** `Sort By:`, but keep the select options.

I have tried this using CSS, however it removes both the text and the select options.

```
#SortOptions {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Why not just delete the text "Sort by:"...? No CSS needed, really. If you hide the whole `div` you'll also hide the `select` nested into it.

Comment: As I mentioned in the first sentence, I'm using jquery and css to override a websites default html - I have no access to that websites default code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Hide text node in element, but not children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196630/hide-text-node-in-element-but-not-children)
You can set the visibility style to "hidden" for the element and override it for the children.

```
#SortOptions{
    visibility: hidden;
}
#SortOptions select{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/3u5zs5rj/

Answer (score 1):

Remove specific word using jQuery

```js
var div = $('#SortOptions');
var newText = div.html().replace('Sort by:','');
div.html(newText)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="SortOptions">
    Sort by: 
    <select id="SortMain" class="improvedcatalogdropdown">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Relevance</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the text completely using `innerHTML` and `replace()` in Javascript.

```
document.getElementById('SortOptions').innerHTML = document.getElementById('SortOptions').innerHTML.replace("Sort by:","");
```