# Hide "non-element" using css

Tags: css

Following code:

```
<li>
    <a href="...">bla</a>
    <span>blabla</span>
    hidethistext
</li>
```

How could I hide the "non-element" "hidethistext" with `display:none` using CSS without affecting everything else? Meaning, what would be the right selector?
Tried using `:not(..)` but that seemed not the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. With css you can only select elements. The `:not` selector is used to select an element that is not of class `x`, does not have id `y` or is not element `z`. But `hidethistext` is just a textnode, which cannot be selected. The only solution is to wrap it in a `<span/>` element with another class then the first `span`

Comment: Seems you're right. Unfortunately, I'm not the one who produces the code, this is done by an application. I'm just here to make it look good ;). So I can't wrap it into a `span`.

Comment: Or call the guy and ask him if he wants to wrap it in a span :p You can also use javascript to do it dynamically. Although that's a suboptimal solution...

Comment: I'll file a bug at phabricator.wikimedia.org ;). Actually thought about javascript too. Suboptimal, as you say, but may be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `visibility` property since it can be overridden.

```
<li>
    <a href="...">bla</a>
    <span>blabla</span>
    hidethistext
</li>
```

CSS

```
/* hide all elements (including textnode "hidethistext" */
li {
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* set other elements to visible */
li span, li a {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Example here on [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v29Ltxxg/).

Related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196630/hide-text-node-in-element-but-not-children).

Comment: Still the browser reserves space for the text. That's what I'm trying to prevent.

Comment: @drhirn in that case you'll need to set it's `display` to `none`. You'll have to put it into a separate `<span>` tag to accomodate for that. Look at @giorgio's answer if that's the functionality you need.