# How to hide elements using css only without id or class

Tags: css

how can I hide only the words "**Piano Lesson**" from this tag using CSS but without an ID or class but using only selectors?

```
<div class="alert alert-success dynamic-alert ">
    <ul>
        <li>
            (Canceled) <a href="http://www.google.ch">July 18, 2017 13:30</a> Piano Lesson
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**I am not able to change the html!**

Comment: You can't select a text node with CSS.

Comment: You should wrap text in `<span>`, and then you'll be able to hide it

Comment: Here you need to put this text "Piano Lesson" in any of html attributes.

Comment: Can you alter your HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide text node in element, but not children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196630/hide-text-node-in-element-but-not-children)

Answer (score 1):

**wrap it in `span` and use internal style.**

*Note:internal style better than inline style.*

```
.alert li a + span {
  display:none;
}
```

```css
.alert li a + span {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-success dynamic-alert ">
    <ul>
        <li>
            (Canceled) <a href="http://www.google.ch">July 18, 2017 13:30</a> <span>Piano Lesson<span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

> **you said :** how could I move the content "(Canceled)" to the place of "Piano Lesson" and replace it?

**With jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    var c = $($('li a')[0].previousSibling).text();
    $($('li a')[0].previousSibling).wrap('<span style="display:none"></style>');
    $($('li a')[0].nextSibling).wrap('<span style="display:none"></style>');
    $('li a').after('<span>' + c + '</span>')
  }) 
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    var c = $($('li a')[0].previousSibling).text();
    $($('li a')[0].previousSibling).wrap('<span style="display:none"></style>');
    $($('li a')[0].nextSibling).wrap('<span style="display:none"></style>');
    $('li a').after('<span>' + c + '</span>')
  }) 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-success dynamic-alert ">
    <ul>
        <li>
            (Canceled)<a href="http://www.google.ch">July 18, 2017 13:30</a>Piano Lesson
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button>Go</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That helped! Any how could I move the content "(Canceled)" to the place of "Piano Lesson" and replace it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="alert alert-success dynamic-alert ">
    <ul>
        <li>
            (Canceled) <a href="http://www.google.ch">July 18, 2017 13:30</a> <span style="display:none;">Piano Lesson</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Just add `Piano Lesson` inside  tags, and use `style="display:none;"` to hide it.

Edit: You can also use this (No extra ID & Class needed)

```css
.alert ul li span{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-success dynamic-alert ">
    <ul>
        <li>
            (Canceled) <a href="http://www.google.ch">July 18, 2017 13:30</a> <span>Piano Lesson</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I can not modify the tag.. I can only chanche the CSS in the stylesheet..

Comment: Edited my answer, you can at least add the span tag around Piano Lesson right? Let me know, if you need something else also

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul li').each(function(){
    var content=$(this).html();
    var check=content.search('Piano Lesson');
    if(check!='-1'){
        content=content.replace('Piano Lesson','');
    }
    $(this).html(content);
})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code.

**Html**

```
<ul>
        <li>
            (Canceled) <a href="http://www.google.ch">July 18, 2017 13:30</a><span> Piano Lesson</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**css**

```
ul li span{display:none}
```

Or another way:

**Html**

```
<ul>
        <li>
            (Canceled) <a href="http://www.google.ch">July 18, 2017 13:30</a><span class="span-style"> Piano Lesson</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**css**

```
ul li .span-style{display:none} or .span-style{display:none}
```

Answer (score 0):

*If you can't edit the html*...you can still get the desired effect but in a hacky way.

**This has no cross browser support yet...and by I mean it won't work on IE or Edge. I tested it in Chrome 59 and FF 54 and all is good there.**

With that being said, [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=-webkit-mask-image) says this will work for at least 89% of users.

```css
.alert li {
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)12.8em, /** <---- manually edit this value to determine the cutoff point **/
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-success dynamic-alert ">
  <ul>
    <li>
      (Canceled) <a href="http://www.google.ch">July 18, 2017 13:30</a> Piano Lesson
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, but could be annoying to have to manually edit this

Comment: @ovokuro I totally agree

Answer (score 0):

Altering the HTML is the best option as others have said.

An alternative method if you can't do that:

```css
.alert ul li {
 font-size: 0;
}

.alert ul li a {
 font-size: 16px;
}

.alert ul li:before {
  content: 'Canceled';
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-success dynamic-alert ">
    <ul>
        <li>
            (Canceled) <a href="http://www.google.ch">July 18, 2017 13:30</a> Piano Lesson
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```