# How to apply css to an HTML item with no selector

Tags: html, css

I have a wordpress website where I need to remove an element from the form.

This is how the element "|" looks like:
[image]

And this is what it looks like on inspecting it with chrome developer tool. :
[image]
I cannot add any selector on it, because I don't control how it is rendered. but I need to get rid of it.

Comment: share  u r website link

Comment: It's better to remove it via your Wordpress form generator tool, it would be very complicated/error-prone code to hide text node

Comment: That is a text node,  so you are going to struggle here. You can not directly select a text node with CSS. There are few ideas discussed in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196630/hide-text-node-in-element-but-not-children

Comment: this looks like plain text within a div. You are right in saying that you can't select this. You need to iterate through childNodes, find the content, and then do parent.removeChild(node)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```js
const a = document.querySelector("a[id^=cred]");
const sib = a.nextSibling;
if (/\s+|\s+/.test(sib.nodeValue)) sib.nodeValue = " "; // a.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(" - "), sib);
```

```html
<div class="toolset-google">
  <a id="credbla">Something</a>
    |
  <a class="toolset-google">something else</bla>
</div>
```