# How to select text in HTML without a tag

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to change the layout of a Wordpress plugin, but I have hit a roadblock.

I can't seem to remove the three dots located at the bottom of the download card. They don't seem to have a selector/tag, even Chrome Developer tools won't let me change them.

Image of the three dots

[image: img1]

How do I select these three dots so that I can hide them? I can't change the HTML structure because it is generated by a shortcode from the plugin.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196630/hide-text-node-in-element-but-not-children) help answering your question?

Comment: Downvoting because you haven't added any HTML code, just an image which is against the guidelines for creating a post. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example If you don't have the energy to write the code, why should we?

Comment: Thank you very much Thum! It worked wonderfully. I couldn't find that thread because I didn't realize it was called a text node. Now I know ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was really curious about this, so I looked it up and finded this: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/how-to-target-only-the-stray-text-inside-a-div/.

It seems that no... you can't target them and therefore you can't hide them. Unless...

I haven't tried anything similar, but maybe a dirty solution could be to target the element containing the dots and set the font-size to 0 (I'm assuming the text inside could dissapear) and then in the child elements set the font-size back to normal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will try and see if it works :)