# Remove unwanted spacing (&nbsp;) between 2 table elements

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to create a page layout with `<table>` elements. The problem I have that it's being auto generated in the DOM extra unwanted spacing, in the form of `&nbsp`. How can I remove it?

**See Images:**
[image]
**Results:**
[image]

**The Challenge:**

The challenge I have. I can **only** use inline styles & no javascript & I **cannot use flex** instead of tables. Since it's going to be used in emails. and not all email clients support flex yet.

```html
<div style="width:375px;margin:0 auto;font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;">
  <table style="width:100%;background-color: aliceblue;border-bottom: 1px #539ecb solid; 
                    border-top: 1px #539ecb solid;color: #334859; text-transform: uppercase;padding:0 15px;">
      <!-- Entries Header -->
      <tr>
          <td style="padding:3px 0;width: 47%;">
              <h5 style="margin:0;">Description</h5>
          </td>
          <td style="text-align: center;width: 25%;">
              <h5 style="margin:0;">Qty</h5>
          </td>&nbsp;
          <td style="text-align: right;">
              <h5 style="margin:0;">Amount</h5>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width: 100%;padding:0 15px;">
      <!-- Entries -->
      <tr>
          <td style="padding:5px 0;width: 50%;">
              <span style="text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 13px;">Office desk</span>
          </td>
          <td style="padding:5px 0;text-align: center;width: 25%;">
              <small style="margin: 0;font-size: 11px;">2 x $217.75</small>
          </td>&nbsp;
          <td style="padding:5px 0;text-align:right;">
              <span style="margin: 0;font-size: 13px;">$435.50</span>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any control over the HTML? How is it being generated?

Comment: The HTML was written by me & is going to be used as a template in emails. and will be used with razor to render in data later

Comment: Probably what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196630/hide-text-node-in-element-but-not-children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the issue is the `&nbsp;`s you intentionally added *within* the table. HTML has strict rules about what can and can't be a direct child of the various table elements.

A [text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) can't be the direct child of a `tr`, which [can contain only](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tr-element):

> Zero or more td, th, and script-supporting elements.

Therefore, the `&nbsp;` text nodes get pushed outside the table. Remove those, and the visual layout will be fixed (I'd still recommend fixing the semantics of the markup, though).

---

*Original answer below*

Your HTML is malformed in any case. What looks to be a table header row and body row are represented as 2 separate tables. Try something like this:

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <thead style="/* styles from what's currently your first table */">
    <tr>
      <!-- content from what's currently your first table -->
      <th>...</th>
      <th>...</th>
      <th>...</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="/* styles from what's currently your second table */">
    <tr>
      <!-- content from what's currently your second table -->
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You are 100% right if this is the only 2 tables I use. The problem is that it's an entire page with multiple tables one after the next.

Comment: By "multiple tables", do you mean multiple _rows_? If so, put the header rows as individual `tr`s inside `thead` and the body rows as individual `tr`s inside `tbody`.

Comment: No multiple tables I mean multiple tables the snippet provided was with only one item for demonstration only

Comment: In that case, just fix the HTML and place the tables as you like. The `&nbsp;`s are only being inserted due to the malformed HTML (HTML tables are a bit finicky).

Comment: Edited answer. Your actual issue is the `&nbsp;`s you added yourself, which are getting pushed out of the table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218390/discussion-between-lionel-rowe-and-ahron-m-galitzky).

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `&nbsp;`s with empty string.

```js
document.querySelector("#our_div").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#our_div").innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');
```

```html
<div id="our_div" style="width:375px;margin:0 auto;font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;display:block;">
  <table style="width:100%;background-color: aliceblue;border-bottom: 1px #539ecb solid; 
                    border-top: 1px #539ecb solid;color: #334859; text-transform: uppercase;padding:0 15px;">
            <!-- Entries Header -->
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:3px 0;width: 47%;">
                    <h5 style="margin:0;">Description</h5>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;width: 25%;">
                    <h5 style="margin:0;">Qty</h5>
                </td>&nbsp;
                <td style="text-align: right;">
                    <h5 style="margin:0;">Amount</h5>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="width: 100%;padding:0 15px;">
            <!-- Entries -->
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px 0;width: 50%;">
                    <span class="item-name" style="text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 13px;">Office desk</span>
                </td>
                <td style="padding:5px 0;text-align: center;width: 25%;">
                    <small class="qty" style="margin: 0;font-size: 11px;">2 x $217.75</small>
                </td>&nbsp;
                <td style="padding:5px 0;text-align:right;">
                    <span class="item-price" style="margin: 0;font-size: 13px;">$435.50</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

Here is pure CSS solution. Adjust `font-size:0` to `div` and `font-size:1rem` to `table`s. CSS can't remove it, but can hide.

```css
#our_div {
  font-size:0;
}

#our_div table {
  font-size:1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="our_div" style="width:375px;margin:0 auto;font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:0;">
<table style="width:100%;background-color: aliceblue;border-bottom: 1px #539ecb solid; 
                    border-top: 1px #539ecb solid;color: #334859; text-transform: uppercase;padding:0 15px;">
            <!-- Entries Header -->
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:3px 0;width: 47%;">
                    <h5 style="margin:0;">Description</h5>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;width: 25%;">
                    <h5 style="margin:0;">Qty</h5>
                </td>&nbsp;
                <td style="text-align: right;">
                    <h5 style="margin:0;">Amount</h5>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="width: 100%;padding:0 15px;">
            <!-- Entries -->
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px 0;width: 50%;">
                    <span class="item-name" style="text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 13px;">Office desk</span>
                </td>
                <td style="padding:5px 0;text-align: center;width: 25%;">
                    <small class="qty" style="margin: 0;font-size: 11px;">2 x $217.75</small>
                </td>&nbsp;
                <td style="padding:5px 0;text-align:right;">
                    <span class="item-price" style="margin: 0;font-size: 13px;">$435.50</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot use Javascript

Comment: Interesting approach, I'm going to try it since I didn't find a better solution. (now i will need to set a font size on each and every element on the template)

Comment: no this is not necessary. just use the css I edited above. this is just 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

It would be far better to do that with JS. In CSS you can try to set some font styles for the div container to hide the " " characters and set the styles to their initial values for the tables (so they do not inherit values from the container).

```
div{
  font-size:0;
  line-height:0;
  color: transparent;
  user-select: none;
}

div>table{
  font-size: 16px; //or any other
  line-height: normal;  //or any other
  color: black;  //or any other
  user-select: auto;
}
```