# How to HIDE part of text with CSS inside span?

Tags: css

How to hide In stock Text only using CSS? Advance wishes..

```html
<span class="option__title option__title testdhana">In stock | <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>12.00</span> | CHICKEN BIRYANI</span>
```

Comment: All conent of testdhana is possible only text "In Stock" without change code no.

Comment: You need JS for this. Or change html...

Comment: This data load in search result if i type anything in search input. So jquery is not response well when i type 3 text in the input.

Comment: Best practice is to wrap the most atomic text you want to target in its own element. Otherwise as mentioned you really need to use JS for this to avoid hacks.

Comment: @TylerH none of the duplicates give an answer for this case :) there is two text node inside the span, if it was only one text node then we can apply this duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15196630/8620333

Comment: OP is asking how to target part of a text node. All of the above dupes apply. The only one that doesn't *directly* apply is the "target direct text and not text within tags" one, but it has useful answers on how to use JS to accomplish OP's goal here.

Comment: Please understand this is not duplicate question. In my case it have two plain text. first and last. middle is another one span.

Answer (score 3):

Use negative text-indent and hide the overflow

```css
.option__title {
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-indent:-60px; /* adjust this */
}
```

```html
<span class="option__title option__title testdhana">In stock | <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>12.00</span> | CHICKEN BIRYANI</span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working fine. I m fighting with this last 3 hrs.

Comment: @Tamilheartz don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your issue

Answer (score -3):

```css
.d-none{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="option__title option__title testdhana"><span class="d-none">In stock</span> | <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>12.00</span> | CHICKEN BIRYANI</span>
```

You can also hide `|` just wrap it also inside `span` if you needed.

Comment: You change the code, without is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I cant add any class or span in "In stock". Its third party js retrieve data.any other solution please.

Comment: In this case try with JavaScript if you have privilege to change otherwise it's not possible in third party js.