# How to style a dynamic html created by PHP

Tags: php, html, css

My php page will generate a dynamic html.

The following is the output;

```
<label class="required">suject *</label>
```

Unfortunately i can't edit the html

Now I need to show '*' in red color.

How I can write the css for that?

Comment: you cannot show _only_ the `*` in red using CSS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165094/css-rule-to-target-text-between-2-tags

Comment: how is it possible that you can edit the php and the css but not the html?

Comment: If you have access to JavaScript too it's no problem.

Comment: Maybe you can do something with `text-replace` http://www.cssportal.com/css-properties/text-replace.htm and `content` http://css-tricks.com/css-content/ but I have no idea how good both area supported in different browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

If you have access to the PHP source code, then you can modify the output accordingly, perhaps wrap the * with `<span>` tags and style the accordingly.

Alternative, you can use JS to do the same:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Loop through all labels with required class
    $('label.required').each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\*/g, '<span class="asterisk">*</span>'));
    });

});
```

And in your CSS, you can style it in any way you want:

```
.required .asterisk {
    color: red;
}
```

See fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/JTesR/

**Even better: Using CSS**

This is written in light of trying to be as semantically correct as possible - you can remove the * character with JS (or changing the PHP code), but use a pseudo-class to add it back to the label element:

```
label.required:after {
    content: '*';
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: @Allendar Neither did he say he did *NOT* want to use JS. Jeez.

Comment: He did say as an alternative, so a -1 is a bit harsh, I have +1 accordingly

Comment: @Allendar The question was how can he do it. I think this is an excellent answer and much more beneficial than everyone else who is firing off -1's

Comment: Thanks guys :) someone is just too trigger happy with downvoting (while not being actually helpful himself)

Comment: I'm really confused, everyone is just voting against and for how to respond to an OP's question. As long as an OP doesn't state to use a certain technology, ask the OP first in comment? I could answer CSS questions all day with JavaScript, and who couldn't. I hardly "fire off" -1's. I'm just saying I'm giving this answer a -1 until the OP confirms JavaScript is ok for him to use. No pun or negativism intended :) Until now Quentin's answer is the only reasonable approach for the OP; CSS in it's current state can't do that.

Comment: `label.required:after { content: '*'; color: red; }` would not work, as the OP can't adjust the original HTML. You'll get `suject **`

Comment: You might want to read what I wrote, first. Before that, get off the high horse.

Answer (score 2):

CSS allows you to select elements (and a limited number of pseudo-elements such as `:first-line`).

There is no way to select "last character", "characters matching `*`" or anything else that would make what you want achievable.

You have to modify the DOM. The easiest way to do that would be to modify the HTML it is generated from. The hacky approach would be to modify it with JavaScript after it has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on Terry's answer: You can simply use `:after` to simulate effect, and place that content over generated HTML.

```
label.required:after {
    content: '*';
    color: red;
    background:white;
    position: relative;
    left: -8px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x2KN7/

Comment: I like the hack. Might cause inconsistencies with other styling tho, like pushing the content away unintended. +1

Comment: To avoid that, OP can use `:nth-child()` or anything else to target only one label.

Comment: He can use absolute positioning, this is just idea.

Comment: Sounds reasonable; as long as the wrapper around the `.required` element has a relative wrapper. But I think what you have now would work fine enough if it's only for the precise case the OP states.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible through CSS, but you can do something with the javascript. If this content is generated on page load then you can hook page load event, get reference to this element and make changes.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.onload = function (e) {
  var col = document.getElementsByClassName("required");
  for (var i=0;i<col.length;i++) {
    if (col[i].innerHTML == "subject *") {
      col[i].innerHTML = "subject&nbsp;<span style='color:red'>*</span>";
    }
  }  
}
</script>
```

Try the above, hopefully it will solve your problem. I have used simple javascript, but if you know a javascript library (YUI, dojo, jquery) then you can do this in 1 or 2 line.